# Cannot print the results if the Get-EC2Tag command is under variable

Tags: powershell

$instanceId = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString(" [http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id"](http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id%22))

$tag = Get-EC2Tag -Filter @{Name="resource-type";Value="instance"},@{Name="key";Value="Name"} | Where-Object ResourceId -eq $instanceId | Select-Object Value | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
Write-Host $tag

Answer (score 0):

This is the results for  Write-Host $tag

Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData